# Can't add to ManyToManyField in Django custom task

Tags: django, many-to-many, django-orm

I have two models in my Django app (`Tag` and `MyModel`).

`MyModel` has a `ManyToManyField` (tags) that uses the `Tag` model

```
class Tag(models.Model):

    CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
        ('topic', 'topic')
    )

    tag = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES)


class MyModel(models.Model):

   id = models.CharField(max_length=30, primary_key=True)
   title = models.CharField(max_length=300, default='')
   author = models.CharField(max_length=300)
   copy = models.TextField(blank=True, default='')
   tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
```

I have a custom Django management task where I delete the `Tags` table, get new data, and refresh the `Tags` table with `bulk_create`

```
Tag.objects.all().delete()

....get new data for Tag table

Tag.objects.bulk_create(new_tags)
```

However after this - if I try to add a tag to an instance of `MyModel.tags`...

```
mymodel_queryset = MyModel.objects.all()

for mymodel in mymodel_queryset
    mymodel.tags.add(5)
```

...I get this error:
**CommandError: insert or update on table "bytes_mymodel_tags" violates foreign key constraint ....
DETAIL:  Key (tag_id)=(5) is not present in table "bytes_tag".**

It seems like the Tag table is empty even though I just updated it

For some reason deleting and resetting the Tag table prevents me from adding to an instance of MyModel.tags. How can I do this?

Note: If I don't first delete and reset the Tags table then I can add to `MyModel.tags` just fine

Comment: Why are you adding 5 ? It should be an instance of tag

Answer (score 2):

Instead of adding random number in `mymodel.tags.add` you have to add Tag object.

```py
mymodel_queryset = MyModel.objects.all()

for mymodel in mymodel_queryset
    mymodel.tags.add(new_tags)
```

Answer (score 2):

Im expanding a little bit on what has already been said here above:

When you have a m2m relationship, if you want to create a new row in the through table by using `add` you have to do so by adding an instance of the corresponding class connected through the relationship.

So if you have `Tag` and `MyModel` and you want to add a `Tag object` to `MyModel`, you have to first create a `MyModel instance` and then add to it a `Tag instance`.

For example:

```
tag_1 = Tag.objects.create(tag="test", category="test") 
my_model_1 = MyModel.objects.create(title="my Title", author="me", copy="xxx")

# This is how you do it
my_model_1.add(tag_1)
```

Et voilà!

Note that when you use `.add(instance)` the `save()` method is built-in so you don't need to call it.